# Send data another contenpage in carouselpage

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have 3 `contentpage` into `carouselpage` in a Xamarin.Forms application. Every `contentpage` contains a `listview` with databinding. I want to send some values of `listview` to next `contentpage` when I selected an item of `listview`.

How can I do it?

I tried:
`this.CurrentPage = this.Children[2];`
but this is not send parameter to another `contentpage` and is not filling `listview`.

Categories are in the `listview` of the first `contentpage`.
Blocks of the selected category are in the `listview` of the second `contentpage`.
Tests of the selected block are in the `listview` of the third `contentpage`.

I would be very grateful for helpful suggestions.

Comment: this sounds like a strange use of a carousel.  This sounds like something that would be a better fit for a standard navigation hierarchy.  But if you want to stick with carousel, use MessagingCenter to pass data.

Comment: It currently works in a standard navigation hierarchy. However, the carouselpage will be much nicer. I thought of using the MessagingCenter, but need to fill in the listview in the second contentpage and show it later?

Comment: Could you provide some code? The link below is the way we used to pass data normally.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#passing-data-when-navigating